# HTML-only fallback for MathML

Tags: html, mathml

[MathML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML) is a web standard for writing mathematics in a way that can be easily zoomed without pixellating (just like SVG), copied and pasted, and read by screen readers.

Chrome are refusing to implement it on the basis that a JavaScript polyfill exists. [(I kid you not.)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152430#c43) Edge's support is ['Not currently planned'](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/mathml/). Thus, it's just Safari and Firefox (and [some EPub readers](http://epubtest.org/testsuite/epub3/feature/mathml/)) that support MathML.

Given that implementation is so spotty, fallback content is 100% necessary. The usual solution for this is [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/); but this doesn't work for users who have JavaScript disabled or, more likely, broken.

We live in an age where HTML easily allows fallback content without JavaScript (see the `<picture>`, `<audio>` and `<video>` tags). Is there some way to do so for MathML?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why they downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no HTML-only way to detect support for MathML.

However, there *is* an SVG way.

The `<switch>` SVG element renders the first direct child of itself where certain boolean attributes on that child are either missing or evaluate to true. One such attribute is the `requiredExtensions` attribute, which mandates that the user agent has to support a particular extension to render the indicated element.

So, if you have an SVG `<foreignObject>` element (used to embed non-SVG elements in SVG) with `requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"` set on it, and *then* put that `<foreignObject>` inside a `<switch>` element, the `<math>` element will be rendered if MathML is supported, and the next element will be if MathML isn't.

So, for a basic MathML example: `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mn>1</mn><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>2</mn></math>` is MathML for 1 + 1 = 2.

A basic SVG fallback for this would be `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="65" height="23"><text y="15" font-size="16">1 + 1 = 2</text></svg>` (more complicated fallbacks could be generated with [Mathjax-Node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node)).

So the completed MathML expression with fallback would be:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="40">
  <switch>
    <foreignObject requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" width="120" height="40">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mn>1</mn><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>2</mn><mtext>MathML</mtext>
      </math>
    </foreignObject>
    <text y="15" font-size="16">1 + 1 = 2 (SVG)</text>
  </switch>
</svg>
```

I have tested the above in Firefox (renders MathML), Edge, IE11 and Chrome (renders SVG). I have not tested Safari, as I don't own a Mac.

EDIT: Safari 9 renders the MathML.

### But I want to support IE8!

Why?

### BECAUSE!

Fine.

If you want to keep the ability to copy + past your math, you can't use an `<picture>` tag to embed your SVG/MathML hybrid - use `<object>` instead:

(I'm using a DataUrl here, but you could just as easily save the SVG as an external file):

```html
<object typemustmatch type="image/svg+xml" data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
  1 + 1 = 2 (You don't support SVG)
</object>
```

(You could render the SVG as a PNG using [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-png) or similar and put in inside the object if you *really* wanted.)

So there you go. A little pre-rendering, and you have a MathML fallback that requires no JavaScript or CSS - just HTML.

EDIT: I have made an NPM package to automate the creation of the MathML, SVG, and PNG. It can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/math-ml-now).

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why they downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

I was not aware of this at the time of my first answer, but you *can* in fact use the `<object>` tag to display MathML directly - the MIME type of MathML is application/mathml+xml.

So you can have one `<object>` tag that points to a mml file, with whatever fallback content you want inside of it (I'd suggest a SVG representation of your equation, possibly in its own `<object>` for a PNG fallback).

I have tested and confirmed this works in Firefox (MathML is displayed), Edge, Internet Explorer 11 and Chrome (SVG is displayed).

EDIT: Safari shows the SVG, not the MathML. (Even through it supports MathML.)